# How to grab piece of html from external html and place it on current

Tags: jquery, input, get, external

This code works perfectly ok, but what if I need the searched item be in another file format, say `.txt`?

It may happen if my search database becomes very large, so I want jQuery to take the input, search for it in another file and if jQuery finds it, show that div on the current page.

Is this possible?

```
<script>
    $('#me').change(function() {
        $('div:contains('+ $.trim(this.value) + ')').css('color','red');
    });
</script>
```

I've found this on stackoverflow, but couldn't recognize how to make them work together

```
var HTML_FILE_URL = '/whatever/html/file.html';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function(data) {
        var fileDom = $(data);
        fileDom.find('h2').each(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$("#divWhereTheContentShouldBeWritten").load("path/externalFile");
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but i also want to replay only the div which contains searched query, that div is searched and found in first part of code, how can i combine them?